# communication links, sytems, or tools?

Tags: vocabulary

Would you please show me what is the difference between these?

communication tools

communication links

communication systems

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to look up the words *tool, link, system* in a dictionary and then ask us about a particular word if the definitions still leave you in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this helps:

Communication `systems`, which enable the exchange of information between members with access to such systems, can be built  with both physical `tools` like smartphones and  walkie-talkies , and digital ones, such as e-mail clients and IM applications,  some or all are `linked` together via a network.

---

`Communication systems` and `communication tools` can really go broad or narrow, depending on how we use them.

So in the 2,000 person IT company I work in, my iPhone is a communication tool. But for me personally the iPhone could play a role of a communication system, which utilizes tools like calls, WhatsApp, and SnapChat to help communicate with the world.